# Input text field and checkbox on same line

Tags: html, css

I have the following bit of HTML, in which I have a form with an input text field and checkbox, among others:

```html
<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <label for="queuename">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="queuename">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="closedqueue">Gender:</label>
  </div>
  ..
</form>
```

This way, they are appearing one below the other. How can I position them on the same line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set display `inline-block`

**CSS**

```
.form-group, .checkbox{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k7m4y42L/5/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have one question -  does a form like this behave any differently when inside a modal window?

Comment: No..it should expect to see the same thing...unless there is some css that overwrite